# How can I create a PNG blob from binary data in a typed array?

Tags: javascript, html, image, url

I have some binary data that happens to be a PNG. I'd like turn it into a blob, get a URL for the blob and display it as an image (or any places else an image URL is valid like css etc..)

Here's what I tried. First I made a small 8x8 red square with yellow "F" image and used pngcrush to make it smaller

You can see the original 91 byte image displays just fine (it's only 8x8 pixels)

[image: 91 byte png]

Then, for this sample, I converted that to an JavaScript array, I copy it into a Uint8Array, I make a blob from that and a URL from the blob, assign that to an image but the image does not display.

```js
var data = new Uint8Array([
  137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,8,0,0,
  0,8,8,2,0,0,0,75,109,41,220,0,0,0,34,73,68,65,84,8,215,99,120,
  173,168,135,21,49,0,241,255,15,90,104,8,33,129,83,7,97,163,136,
  214,129,93,2,43,2,0,181,31,90,179,225,252,176,37,0,0,0,0,73,69,
  78,68,174,66,96,130]);
var blob = new Blob(data, { type: "image/png" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
console.log("data length: " + data.length);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```css
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; }
```

How can I get it to display as a blob url?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The issue was the first argument to the `Blob` constructor is an array of objects to put in the blob so changing it from

```
var blob = new Blob(data, ...
```

to

```
var blob = new Blob([data], ...
```

fixed it

```js
var data = new Uint8Array([
  137,80,78,71,13,10,26,10,0,0,0,13,73,72,68,82,0,0,0,8,0,0,
  0,8,8,2,0,0,0,75,109,41,220,0,0,0,34,73,68,65,84,8,215,99,120,
  173,168,135,21,49,0,241,255,15,90,104,8,33,129,83,7,97,163,136,
  214,129,93,2,43,2,0,181,31,90,179,225,252,176,37,0,0,0,0,73,69,
  78,68,174,66,96,130]);
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "image/png" });
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var img = new Image();
img.src = url;
console.log("data length: " + data.length);
console.log("url: " + url);
document.body.appendChild(img);
```

```css
img { width: 100px; height: 100px; image-rendering: pixelated; }
```

Comment: Holy crap I can't believe all I needed was `[ ]` around `data`.... Mark this the answer and reap the internet points.

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but a question.  I need to do this as well.

Question: how did you get the bytes in `var data = new Uint8Array([` ? And do they include the width/height somehow?

In my case, I need to just start with the raw bytes in the image. The mystery is how to include the width/height as well as the data.