# Set src of an image with object url doesn't work in electron

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron, typed-arrays

I'm building an **electron** ("electron": "^5.0.9", on windows 10 1903) app and have **a nodejs buffer(Uint8Array)**("node": "v10.6.0") containing data like "[255, 216, 255, 224, 0, 16,..." with MIME type "image/jpeg".

I tried to create an object url from the buffer and set the url as the **"src"** of an image, but the image didn't show

I have tried to save it as a jpg on local fs to verify the data and successed

In the **Network** tool, there was a request sent to *blob:file:///60cb1522-25d2-44e9-982d-21e2106dddf8* and the **Status Code** is **200**.

The code like this

```
    const imgBlob = new Blob(buffer, { type: `image/jpeg` })
    const imgUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(imgBlob)
    document.querySelector(`img`).src = imgUrl
```

Expected: the image show correctly

Actual result: the image didn't show

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer here

[How can I create a PNG blob from binary data in a typed array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39062595/how-can-i-create-a-png-blob-from-binary-data-in-a-typed-array)

All I need is just a [ ] to wrap the buffer like

```
const imgBlob = new Blob([buffer], { type: `image/jpeg` })
```

According to the MDN

> var aBlob = new Blob(array [, options]);
>
> **array** is **an Array of** *ArrayBuffer, ArrayBufferView, Blob, DOMString objects, or a mix of any of such objects*, that will be put inside the Blob. DOMStrings are encoded as UTF-8.

[Blob()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)

Holy crap!